# how to create 2 foreign to the same table laravel 10?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-10

I am creating a migration in Laravel and I need to reference the same table 2 times. I explain:
The "inventory" table has the "responsible" and "created by" fields that refer to the user table. The person responsible and the creator may be the same person in certain cases.

This is the migration code:

```php
Schema::create('inventory', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('type');
            $table->string('state', 50);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained(
                table: 'user',
                indexName: 'created_inventory_id'
            )->cascadeOnUpdate()->restrictOnDelete();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained(
                table: 'user',
                indexName: 'responsible_inventory_id'
            )->cascadeOnUpdate()->restrictOnDelete();
            $table->foreignId('area_id')->constrained(
                table: 'area',
                indexName: 'area_inventory_id'
            )->cascadeOnUpdate()->restrictOnDelete();
        });
```

When I run the migration it gives me the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42701]: Duplicate column: 7 ERROR:  column "user_id" was specified more than once (Connection: pgsql, SQL: create table "inventory"
```

How could I resolve that?

Comment: Can you explain what is this in English _fue especificada más de una vez_ (Weird that people who are willing to help have to do the heavy lifting of google translation)? You have specified `user_id` twice in `foreignId` method!

Comment: Because I need it. The inventory manager and the inventory creator are two different users. That is, they are different fields but they refer to the same table.

Comment: Give different names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reference the same "user" table for both the "inventory manager" and " inventory creator" fields in the "inventory" table, you should give them distinct column names. Here's an updated migration code that resolves the issue:

```
Schema::create('inventory', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('type');
            $table->string('state', 50);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreignId('inventory_creator_user_id')->constrained(
                table: 'user',
                indexName: 'created_inventory_id'
            )->cascadeOnUpdate()->restrictOnDelete();
            $table->foreignId('inventory_manager_user_id')->constrained(
                table: 'user',
                indexName: 'responsible_inventory_id'
            )->cascadeOnUpdate()->restrictOnDelete();
            $table->foreignId('area_id')->constrained(
                table: 'area',
                indexName: 'area_inventory_id'
            )->cascadeOnUpdate()->restrictOnDelete();
        });
```